# Close Popup after extension installed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For example, in this LandingPage for this extension "videodownloadconverter.com/index.jhtml", When you click in continue, this opens a POPUP with extension url and when you install the extension, the Popup closes automatically

I understand that I have to use "chrome.tabs.remove" in the bg.js

What is the correct way to use it?

Thank You!

Comment: The actual solution depends on how exactly that popup is opened, but I guess something like chrome.tabs.query({url: `'https://foo/bar*'`}, tabs => { if (tabs.length) chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[0].id) }) - see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).